# Task not running (especially cleanup service, compact blobstore)

Tags: java, nexus3

Our Jenkins produces snapshots (at least daily) and stores them in a 'snapshots' repository, hence we have a lot of snapshots laying around.
We are using nexus3 and up until version ~3.21 i had (presumably) no problems with cleanup and compact blobstore - The disk space was not getting out of hand, cleanup, deletion of unused snapshots and compact blobstore tasks were running successfully.

The problem now is, that in the nexus ui it states, that these tasks are 'RUNNING' but there is not output about their status what so ever in the logs (even on TRACE on ROOT).
Also I've written some groovy scripts to identify old artifacts, which do their logging on INFO and even these tasks do not output anything.

Does anybody know how to investigate this problem further or even better how to fix this?
I did not find anything about such behavior here or in the nexus docu.

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to mention, that I've deleted all tasks (which where deletable) and created the from scratch (multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

The Scheduler albeit logging suggested otherwise was the culprit. I've remove the Scheduler (I've never touched) an recreated it. Now the tasks actually were running.